# Best practice in taking control over logging in multi-module maven project

Tags: maven, logging, log4j

I have a problem. There is a huge maven project with 10 modules.

The problem is that I can't take control over logging. When project passes maven phases (clean->install->test->itest...) it produces tons of logs. These logging settings come from multiple dependecies and logging implementations: commons-logging, log4j, logback, e.t.c.

I would like to avoid keeping an instance of log configuration in each module.

I would like to take control over it using single file. How can I do that? Where can I read about it?

Comment: Investigate the use of SLF4J: http://www.slf4j.org/

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a separate module (app-logging) of it and add it as a dependency to the other modules.